# Setup 100+ forwarder email addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, email

I have a requirement from a client, they want to be able to setup 100+ email addresses to be used for testing purposes. They don't need to be able to send emails but we need to be able to receive them.

These would be used as test accounts in their application for user accounts and any emails sent to them should be forward onto one central email address.
And of course they want to use as low cost a solution as possible.

This is pretty out of my wheelhouse but they are currently using AWS for their hosting and workmail for their actual email accounts so i did want to see if I could perhaps use the simple mail service for something like this. However I haven't been able to find any good solution to actually doing this.

What would be a good way to setup this requirement? Are there any services that can be used to do this or should I continue with the idea of using simple mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post from an AWS staff member on [their forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=260572) you can use SES for this. The steps are:

- Verify your domain - maybe you need a different domain? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-verification.html
- Create an email receipt rule  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-receipt-rules.html

Alternatively get any decent email service and set up a catchall address. I use FastMail which I can confirm does this, but I suspect most email services can do this.